# Can I delete an existing question which is not accepting anymore answers?

Tags: discussion

[I posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643797/how-to-identify-boundaries-and-robust-bva-for-any-website) that I think is clear enough, but that other people downvoted without giving any comments, as well as not commenting what is unclear about the question.

As per my understanding, the question is clear, but no luck. So, can I delete this question, as my account is being blocked?

Comment: Voting on meta doesn't affect your reputation and does not contribute to a question ban on the main site.

Comment: You can delete the question. If you're currently banned it will make it harder to recover from that ban though.

Comment: Regarding the question itself: It is to me very unclear what you are asking. Are you asking how to identify the boundaries (test cases)? Or are you looking for a tool to perform the testing? In the first case: How should we know that? We don't know the website any better than you do. Also note, that all relevant information for a question must be present in the question itself. Linking to some external site is not enough.

Comment: It's really hard to say how to improve the question because it's hard to say what the question even is. What test framework or even programming language would you even want to write the test cases in? Seeing how both the title and body ask for "any website" and "any suggestions", [what *specific, practical* problem is the question about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: You might be better off accepting the 3 experienced users who say it is unclear and trying to make it more clear, rather than ignoring them and saying it is clear.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/70643797) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/70064324) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/69955371) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/69764759)

Comment: "So, can I delete this question, as my account is being blocked?" - You seem to think deleting the question will help. I'm sorry, it won't.

Comment: @Zoe no need in such comments anymore because now [users can see all their deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375078/165773)

Comment: "So, can I delete this question, as my account is being blocked?" - This will only drive you further away from the quality threshold which will result in lifting the question ban.  Deleting questions will not lift a question ban. The fact 75% of your deleted questions were deleted by you, it seems you have a habit of deleting questions, that are not well received.  Which is the primary reason you are currently question banned.  The other reason is the fact out of all the questions that have not been deleted you have next to zero upvotes.

Comment: Vicky, you asked this meta question 7 hours ago and have received a bit of attention. Have you replied to any of the comments or the answer yet? I ask because sometimes a comment might have been deleted.

Comment: @SecurityHound Noted all the points. I will take care of this from next time onwards and edit the existing questions that are unclear enough.

Comment: @Gimby Ok. I will not delete it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This question *is* unclear (and overly broad) for a number of reasons.

First of all, the question is asking us to write your tests for you, which really isn't what Stack Overflow is for. You're [expected](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) to at least *try* to solve the problem on your own prior to posting here, which it appears that you didn't.

Secondly, you don't include any of the code you're asking about in the question itself; rather, you expect people to go off-site and look at an entire web site in order to figure out what the question is.

Third, boundary value analysis is only meaningful if you know what the actual boundaries are, which you don't specify in your question. You give no indication of which code you're trying to test, what the code's supposed to do, or what the valid input ranges are.

Fourth, the question appears to be asking for a complete tutorial on how to perform Boundary Value Analysis, which Stack Overflow also isn't for. You're expected to research Boundary Value Analysis on your own prior to posting here and then ask a question if you're still confused. For more details, please see: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Finally, the link doesn't appear to even be your site. From the [Don't Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask),

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Asking about how to test someone else's site is not an "actual problem that you face."

In short, the question was premature (because you should've read a tutorial about BVA before posting it), not practical (because it doesn't appear to be about a problem that you actually face), too broad (because you didn't include any evidence of prior effort and were expecting us to do the whole thing for you), and unclear (because you didn't include any details about what you were actually trying to test).

Comment: Noted. I will take care of all the points which all you guys have explained to me. Thanks for this suggestion